# typeNum to load content without headers. Does not work in other languages then default

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I have this typoscript to request content only (without the header, css, js, etc)

```
ajaxCall = PAGE
ajaxCall {
    typeNum = 999
    config.disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    config.disablePrefixComment = true
    # config.additionalHeaders = Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    config.metaCharset = UTF-8

    10 = COA
    10 <  styles.content.get
    10.stdWrap.prepend > # supress feEditAdvanced-firstWrapper - Bug in typo3 4.3.1
}
```

This works fine as long as I am in the default language. But when I want to use this pageType on another language `&L=1` it does not work and I get nothing.

I tested around a bit and found out that the problem is here

```
10 = COA
10 <  styles.content.get
```

It looks like when there is a language parameter the `styles.content.get` is empty.

**Edit**: I try to get the content with my own CONTENT object

```
ajaxCallw = PAGE
ajaxCallw {
    typeNum = 1000
    config.disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    config.disablePrefixComment = true
    # config.additionalHeaders = Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    config.metaCharset = UTF-8

    10 = CONTENT
    10 {
        table = tt_content 
        select.orderBy = sorting 
        select.where = colPos=0 
        select.languageField = 4
    }

}
```

It looks like `select.languageField = 4` gets completly ignored, as it still displays me the content from the default langauge. And when I call a URL with `&type=1000&L=4` it still does not show me anything. (Without the `L=4` parameter it shows me the default language content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated` was the problem.

Adding: `ajaxCall.config.sys_language_overlay = 0` solved the problem.

```
ajaxCall = PAGE
ajaxCall {
    typeNum = 999
    config.disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    config.disablePrefixComment = true
    # config.additionalHeaders = Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    config.metaCharset = UTF-8
    config.sys_language_overlay = 0

    10 = COA
    10 <  styles.content.get
    10.stdWrap.prepend > # supress feEditAdvanced-firstWrapper - Bug in typo3 4.3.1
}
```

I am not sure why exactly this works now..

Answer (score 2):

select.languageField is a pointer to the field in the database

```
select.languageField = sys_language_uid
```

As far as I remember the language variable is not parsed by default, so you have to set it yourself

```
ajaxCall {
    # your code
    config.sys_language_uid = 0
}

# condition for the language. Adjust it to your language id
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
ajaxCall.config.sys_language_uid = 1
[global]
```

Comment: Okey, to test it I directly set `ajaxCall.config.sys_language_uid = 4` and I get the content from the language 4! But only If I not set any langauge parameter in the url. I will test now a bit more (maybe another setting in `[globalVar = GP:L = 4]`is the problem) and update my question after that

Comment: Its the `sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated` who makes the problem

Comment: Thank you, you lead me in the right direction. It works now (but not sure why ecactly) If you want to edit your answer (see my answer) I will accept yours.

Comment: `sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated` should only be used if you have configured `sys_language_mode` to a non default value. To see that one must see all the TS (or at least the config part) you are using.

Answer (score 0):

styles.content.get is just a CONTENT object that gets the content of col0 (rendered true or with css_styled_content)  you can better just fetch your content with your own CONTENT object, thus you can have more control of it.

Comment: That is what I try right now without success. I will update my question